Exceso de procesos postgres.exe zombie consume toda la memoria. Server 2012 R2
Estoy realizando un proceso de Sincronización de base de datos, una es OpenEdge Progress 10.2b [32 bits] (Origen) y PostgreSQL 12 [64 bits] (Destino). Se creo un Servicio Windows con una aplicación Worker Service en C#, utilizando Entity Framework Core 8 y el paquete Npgsql EF Core, para realizar la conexión a PostgreSQL. En si el Servicio Windows consume una API Web de Progress (WebSpeed) para leer los datos que va a escribir en PotgreSQL 12, se aplicaron los Disponse() y using para el contexto de la mejor manera para liberar la entidad correctamente.
Pero ocurre lo siguiente al momento de realizar las consultas en el servidor en donde se encuentra PostgreSQL 12 se crean los procesos de conexión por cada consulta pero nunca se liberan, a pesar que son de un tamaño pequeño 20K por cada uno, pero se crean demasiados que llenan y colapsan la memoria. La cantidad de consultas que realiza es un promedio de 5 mil por minuto. El sistema operativo del servidor es Windows Server 2012 R2, 6GB Ram.
Los procesos zombies los vizualizo a traves de la aplicacion RamMap ejecutada en el servidor. El scroll de RamMap se pierde de la gran cantidad de procesos postgres.exe zombies ocupando espacio. Intente finalizarlos por consola usando los comandos "taskkill.exe /F /PID ", en donde devuelve que no encontro el proceso, utilice "rundll32.exe advapi32.dll,ProcessIdleTasks" sin ningún resultado. Detuve el servicio PostgreSQL y los procesos no liberaban memoria, cerre PostgreSQL desde el Administrador de Tareas usando "Finalizar el arbol de procesos" sin poder liberar la memoria. La unica opción era reiniciar el servidor.
Esto no ocurre solamente con el Servicio Windows mensionado, cuando se realizan consultas desde pgAdmin 4, Navicat, Azure Data Studio, DBeaver CE y aplicaciones en Python. Tampoco se liberan.
Espero haber sido claro y puedan ayudarme, de igual manera quedo atento a sus recomendaciones y agradecido por cualquier aporte. Dejo a continuación parte de la información arriba indicada.

Ejemplo del Codigo en C# del Servicio Windows, en donde dataSync contiene los datos y parametros que va a ingresar, actualizar o eliminar en Postgres, las variables pgoe (Progress OpenEdge), pgsql (PostgreSQL) y ds (DataSet con los registros de la DB origen). Es una tarea por cada tabla que se actualiza.
private async Task Set_ccanocob(Ttsyncpgsql dataSync)
{
  Ccanocob? pgoe;
  Ccanocob? pgsql;
  await using (var db = new SigaPruebasDbContext())
  {
    pgsql = await db.Ccanocobs.FindAsync(dataSync.RECID);

    if (dataSync.Evento == "W" && ds != null && ds.ttccanocob != null)
    {
      pgoe = ds.ttccanocob.FirstOrDefault(t => t.PgoeRecid == dataSync.RECID);

      // Create
      if (pgsql == null && pgoe != null)
        await db.Ccanocobs.AddAsync(pgoe);

      // Update
      if (pgsql != null && pgoe != null)
        pgsql = pgoe;
    }
    else if (dataSync.Evento == "D")
    {
      // Delete
      if (pgsql != null)
        db.Ccanocobs.Remove(pgsql);
    }

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    await db.DisposeAsync();
  }
}

Un detalle adicional, en el servidor no inicia pgAdmin 4.


Tiene pinta que te se colo un virus o un minador de crypto en el servidor, pues espero que tu aplicaciones esten liberando bien las conexiones, pero pinta a lo primer que comento sobre el virus

En realidad no creo, porque los PID de los procesos coinciden con los que se quedan zombie. de todos modos voy a verificar las aplicaciones en memoria.

el problema se presenteba por el antivirus que escaneaba los procesos progres.exe y al liberarlos estos quedaban zombies se ajusto el antivirus y no volvio a ocurrir.
